# Python 3.3.2 - Creating a List of the Length of Words

Tags: python, python-3.x, count

I have a string of words with punctuation, let's say for example...

```
string = 'Did the quick brown fox *really* jump over the fence?'
```

I have filtered out the punctuation, so it is now:

```
'Did the quick brown fox really jump over the fence'
```

And I have split it up into a list.

```
list = string.split()
```

Now, with `list`, I now need to count the length of each word into a list, with the length of the list being the longest word. The setting out of the list will be as follows:

```
lengthList = [1_letter_words, 2_letter_words, 3_letter_words, ...]
```

So, for `string`, it would be:

```
lengthList = [0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 1]
```

Unfortunately, I am having trouble doing this. Can anyone please provide any assistance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't want to harangue you (at all, but certainly not) without giving you a proper answer, so skip ahead if you don't care about good coding practices.

**Don't** use variable names like `list` and `string` because - in the case of `list` - that's the name of the type you're making. In fact, that's how you make an empty instance of the type you're making:

```
something=list()       # this is an empty list!
```

this would make it confusing to reference `list[2]` or something along those lines. So you clearly didn't hit any errors, but for the sake of readability, try to come up with meaningful variable names.

Okay, I'm done with my rant, code you're looking for is

```
st='Did the quick brown fox really jump over the fence'.split()
c=[len(i) for i in st] # gives [3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 6, 4, 4, 3, 5]
counts=[0]*max(c)      # gives [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(len(c)):
  counts[c[i]-1]+=1    # adds 1 to each index of c[i] (we subtract 1 because of 0-based indices)
print(counts)          # gives us the answer: [0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 1]
```

I made some of these steps way more advanced than the challenge you're presenting kind of to discourage you from using it in an assignment, if that happens to be your goal. Some of the tools used in this solution are at least **a little** further ahead of what you're working with, but if you're just learning Python for the reward of understanding code then I hope this will be most illuminating and maybe get you thinking about some of the radically cool stuff you can do concisely with Python. With all that said, let's walk through it:

I'm going to assume that the `st` assignment is clear enough that we don't need to discuss it, but note that I split it right there when I assign it. I'm just being lazy and we could do it in two steps, but this isn't the meat of the problem so let's move on.

```
c=[len(i) for i in st]
```

just means "for each element, which we'll call `i`, in `st`, give me back `len(i)` in a list, and make that list `c`". That might seem daunting, but list comprehensions are really not all that bad, and as you can see they save you quite a bit of time in coding. This is a pretty modest implementation of it, really.

```
counts=[0]*max(c)
```

says to make a list with `0`s in each space, and make it repeat however many times is the `max` of `c`. So this will take the longest word, in this case the 6-letter word 'really', and make the list 6 elements long. This will ensure that we have a list with spaces for every length word we encounter.

```
for i in range(len(c)):
  counts[c[i]-1]+=1
```

Oh boy, now we're cooking. See that we're iterating through the list `c`, so each item we get through it will be the lengths of the corresponding words:

- The first element will be `3`, corresponding to `Did`.
- The second element will be `3`, corresponding to `the`.
- ...
- The last element will be `5`, corresponding to `fence`.

So that's what `c[i]` is about, but what is `counts[c[i]-1]`? Well `counts` is going to add `1` to every length you find, so it'll add `1` to a bin when it has a word 3 characters long. `c[i]` will give you `3` on the first element, but since lists are 0-indexed (lists start at 0 and goes up from there), you need to compensate - hence the `-1`. So we see `counts[c[i]-1]` and now it makes a little more sense, right?

```
counts[c[i]-1] # this means counts[3-1] which means go find the bin corresponding to counts[2]

# ---v   this one
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

and `+=1` simply means "add 1 to whatever was there already".

Python will happily iterate through that and give you the answer.

Comment: I was using those names as an example; my actual program does not actually use those.

Comment: Although you made many incorrect assumptions (that I am just starting out in Python, that this is for an assignment, my current level of coding, etc), this post was still highly informative, and I will use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
Data = 'Did the quick brown fox really jump over the fence'
Freq = Counter([len(words) for words in Data.split()])
print ([Freq[Num] if Num in Freq else 0 for Num in range(1, max(Freq)+1) ])
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 1]
```

**Easily understandable version**

```
from collections import Counter
Data = 'Did the quick brown fox really jump over the fence'
Freq = Counter([len(words) for words in Data.split()])
Result = []
for Num in range(1, max(Freq)+1):
    if Num in Freq:
        Result.append(Freq[Num])
    else:
        Result.append(0)
print (Result)
```

Comment: This is a good answer. However, you can do without the square brackets in your `Counter` call. That is, use a generator expression rather than a list comprehension. For a short text like the example the difference will be small, but for a large text (thousands of words) the generator expression will use a lot less memory.

Comment: I didnt know that it would work. Why does it work? `Counter(len(words) for words in Data.split())` Does Counter treat the input as a tuple in this case?

Comment: Like most containers, `Counter`'s constructor accepts any iterable object. So a generator expression works just fine, since iteration is the whole point of generators.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
>>> words = [len(word) for word in "this is a sentence".split()]
>>> words.sort()
>>> words
[1, 2, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'Did the quick brown fox really jump over the fence'
L = string.split()
D = {}    
res = []

for w in L: #store words lenght as keys and repetition as values 
    if len(w) in D:
        D[len(w)] += 1 #increase by one if had seen word with same lenght.
    else:
        D[len(w)]  = 1 #initialize hash with value one if had not seen word with that length  before. 

res = [D.get(x, 0) for x in range(1, max(D.keys()) + 1)]

print(res)
#[0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original_str = "This is a demonstration"
num_words_list = list(original_str.split())
num_words_list = [len(i)for i in num_words_list]
```

Comment: It is highly unclear whether you are trying to "find the length of the longest word in the sentence" or "find the number of times words of different lengths appear in the sentence" - say "two words of length 1, four words of length 2, one word of length 5"? Your solution above works only if it is the first case; in which case also, it is incomplete.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.